# How to enable hardware virtualization using VagrantFile with provider as vmware_esxi?

Tags: vagrant, virtualization, vagrantfile, esxi

I am trying to run a few services on a VM that is created/controlled by the vagrant for which I am using the provider as vmware_esxi

As per vagrant this is the repository for the vmware_esxi plugin:
https://github.com/josenk/vagrant-vmware-esxi

I require the VM to support hardware virtualization for which I running a couple of steps post bringing up the VM. Following are the steps

`1. shut down VM
 2. locate vmx location (find / -name *.vmx)
 3. setting echo 'vhv.enable = "TRUE"' at the end of vmx file`

What I want to know is if the above three steps are supported by the plugin with a vagrant config? Something that can set in the VagrantFile

My current vagrant file is as follows:

```
 VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
 Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
 config.ssh.forward_agent = true
 config.vm.define CFG_MASTER_NODE_NAME do |x|
     x.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
     x.vm.provider :vmware_esxi do |v|
         v.esxi_hostname = '10.73.40.10'
         v.esxi_username = 'root'
         v.esxi_password = 'sometext'
         v.vmname = 'new_vm'
         v.memsize = 6144
         v.numvcpus = 4 
end
end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do this. The feature was undocumented in the plugin. You could use custom settings for the same.

```
x.vmx_custom_settings = [['vhv.enable', 'True']]
```

adding this to the vagrant file would solve the issue